# How to convert date format to custome date format?

Tags: c#, string, datetime

I have the following output in string:

```
24/05/15 11:40:50 AM
```

now I want to convert this string into -> `2015-05-24 11:40:50.000`

I have tried below method but it gives me error :

> String was not recognized as a valid DateTime.

```
DateTime.ParseExact("24/05/15 11:40:50 AM",
                    "yyyy-MM-dd HH:mm:ss", 
                    CultureInfo.InvariantCulture);
```

Comment: You misunderstood the purpose of DateTime.ParseExact: it creates a DateTime given a string representing the date and its format (https://msdn.microsoft.com/library/w2sa9yss%28v=vs.110%29.aspx)

Answer (score 4, accepted):

From [documentation](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/system.datetime.tryparseexact%28v=vs.110%29.aspx);

> Converts the specified string representation of a date and time to its
>   DateTime equivalent. **The format of the string representation must
>   match a specified format exactly.**

In your case, they are not.

First, you can parse it to `DateTime` with specific format and you can generate a string representation with a specific format from that `DateTime`. Like;

```
string s = "24/05/15 11:40:50 AM";
DateTime dt;
if(DateTime.TryParseExact(s, "dd/MM/yy hh:mm:ss tt", CultureInfo.InvariantCulture,
                          DateTimeStyles.None, out dt))
{
    Console.WriteLine(dt.ToString("yyyy-MM-dd hh:mm:ss.fff"));
}
```

Prints;

```
2015-05-24 11:40:50.000
```

Comment: @deepak Sorry, deleted that part. You will not need `Dump()`. It is an extension method of [LINQPad](https://www.linqpad.net/) which is the tool that I almost always use for Stack Overflow questions.

Comment: it is not working if string is  `24/05/15 9:39:34 AM` .

Comment: oh..i got the solution.  i have put another else if with `h:mm:ss` and its done

Comment: @deepak Exactly, [`hh` format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#hhSpecifier) for 12-hour clock which is `01` to `12` when additional leading zero for single digits but [`h` format specifier](https://msdn.microsoft.com/en-us/library/8kb3ddd4.aspx#hSpecifier) is for `1` to `12` in 12-hour clock without leading zeros for single digits.